# How to connect to ShiftPlanning.com API using ColdFusion CFHTTP

Tags: json, api, coldfusion

The ShiftPlanning API documentation for authentication (https://www.shiftplanning.com/api/authentication/) requires a POST request sent in JSON format as follows:

```
{
  "key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "request": {
    "module": "staff.login",
    "method": "GET",
    "username": "xxxxxxx",
    "password": "xxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Seems pretty straightforward, but I don't seem to be connecting to the API. When I CFDUMP the CFHTTP response all I get is the page's HTML source in the filecontent value of the structure, no JSON.

Here's the code I'm using for the CFHTTP call:

```
<!--- set values for API authentication --->
<cfset stFields = {
    "key" = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "request" = {
        "module" = "staff.login",
        "method" = "GET",
        "username" = "xxxxx",
        "password" = "xxxxx"
    }
}>

<!--- Send an authentication request to SHIFTPLANNING API --->
<cfhttp method="post" url="https://www.shiftplanning.com/api/" timeout="30">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(stFields)#" />
</cfhttp>
```

When I CFDUMP serializeJSON(stFields) I get:

```
{
 "request": {
   "username":"xxxxx",
   "module":"staff.login",
   "method":"GET",
   "password":"xxxxx"
  },
"key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You probably want to dump the response, not the stuff being sent out

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did dump the response, but it's not a JSON response, just the the standard CFHTTP response that you would get from any regular HTML page (e.g. cfhttp.filecontent contains the HTML source code for the page). Based on that, it doesn't seem like I'm connecting with the API at all. I only dumped what I'm sending to confirm that the info was properly formatted JSON data going in to the API.

Comment: Are you able to get the successful response using https://www.shiftplanning.com/api/explorer/ ? The debugging on chrome seems to suggest that you need to post the body as `urlencoded` with header as `<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: I get a successful response when using the API Explorer tool on shiftplanning.com/api/explorer, so I know my credentials are good (key, username, password). I'm not able to get a JSON response at all using either shiftplanning.com/api or shiftplanning.com/api/explorer  as the URL with CFHTTP. Tried using URLEncodedFormat with the header you suggested, but that didn't get a JSON response either.

Comment: @vlad-o : the body param also needs to be `urlencoded`. Did you check the chrome debugger to check how the request is being sent on the explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Chrome dev tools on the api explorer, it seems they are passing in the JSON data in a form field called `data`. Changing your `cfhttp` call to this returned JSON data for me:

```
<!--- Send an authentication request to SHIFTPLANNING API --->
<cfhttp method="post" url="https://www.shiftplanning.com/api/" timeout="30" charset="utf-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="data" value="#serializeJSON(stFields)#" />
</cfhttp>
```